# Get array with no key json_decode CURL

Tags: arrays, json

i have response from API like this

```
  "user_settings": {..},
  "users_info": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      "notable_users_pcr": 0.245714,
      "users_with_pcr": 0.853978,
      "users_type": [
        {
          "code": "town_1",
          "weight": 0.134769
        },
        {
          "code": "town_2",
          "weight": 0.094154
        },
        {
          "code": "town_3",
          "weight": 0.16633
        },
        {
          "code": "town_4",
          "weight": 0.604747
        }
      ],
      "users_class": "low",
      "users_reachability": [
        {
          "code": "-500",
          "weight": 0.499692
        },
        {
          "code": "500-1000",
          "weight": 0.264352
        },
        {
          "code": "1000-1500",
          "weight": 0.101187
        },
        {
          "code": "1500-",
          "weight": 0.134769
        }
      ],
```

i use CURL to fetch the data json_decode and everything work, but i cant get the data from  **users_reachability**

i try like this but **users_reachability** not work to fetch the data row 0, 1, 2, 3,

```
  $responeds = json_decode($authToken,true);
// Work
  $get_success = $responeds['users_info']['success'];
// try those but not work
  $get_success =  $responeds['users_info']['data']['users_type];
  $get_success =  $responeds['users_info']['data']['users_type][0];
  $get_success =  $responeds['users_info']['data']['users_type][][0];
  $get_success =  $responeds['users_info']['data']['users_type][''][0];
```

errors shows up

```
Warning: Undefined array key "users_info" ..
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ..
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ..
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ..
```

The Goal how can i get the value from **users_info -> data -> users_type -> 1 OR 2 OR 3**

Comment: @YourCommonSense dear friend, How now i'll get the result if no body helps me. to understand the point exactly in my code? i followed the answerd you put but not exactly helps my point. anyway in this world we must only PAY to get what we looking for nothing for Free..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**users_reachability** can be accessed just fine:

[image]

Comment: i face this errors `Warning: Undefined array key "users_info" in..` `Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in`  in localhost ? may i know why

Comment: Most probably because the string that you're providing to JSON_DECODE is not a valid JSON.

Comment: `$responeds = json_decode($authToken,true);$get_success = $responeds['users_info']['data']['users_type'][0];echo $get_success` this is what im doing but i got the error message ;(

Comment: Throw away your code and use the one from the screenshot - it certainly does work without any errors. OR, call `json_last_error_msg()` after `json_decode()` if you want to see whether your JSON was valid.